# "glibc detected - double free or corruption" during memcpy of complex array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, memcpy, complex-numbers

I have a 2D array/matrix of complex numbers. I want copy a row of this 2D array to a 1D array. I use the complex library and gcc version 4.5.1 on x86_64-suse-linux. I dynamically allocate the arrays using new. Using memcpy I transfer an array of the 2D matrix to the 1D array. It works just fine. The problem is that when I delete the arrays it crashes. I have no idea why or what. When I used valgrind to debug (I'm no expert in it) the following message is obtained.

```
==20516== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==20516==    at 0x4C24F6E: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20516==    by 0x400BBC: main (complex.cpp:29)
==20516==  Address 0x590f290 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 160 free'd
==20516==    at 0x4C24F6E: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20516==    by 0x400B86: main (complex.cpp:27)
```

I post the whole code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<complex>
using namespace std;

int main(){
complex<double> **array = new complex<double>*[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) array[i]=new complex<double>[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
                array[i][j]=complex<double> (i,j+1); abs(array[i][j]) << "]" << endl;
        }
}

complex<double>* b = new complex<double>[10];
memcpy(&b,&array[2],sizeof(array));
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << array[2][i] << "\t" << b[i] << endl;
}

delete[] b;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        delete[] array[i];
}
delete[] array;

}
```

So, is there any other fast way to copy the array "array" to "b" to avoid this error?  When I use just a double array instead of a complex array. this problem is not observed. Also, is the problem with the dynamic allocation of the complex array? Because I seem to remember that I had some problem related to dynamic allocation of the complex arrays in the past while using new/delete. But I think I managed to overcome it by static allocation. Should I change how I dynamically allocate complex arrays?

Comment: You should consider using vectors.

Comment: I'm slowly moving in that direction. Will be there soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate cause of the problem is

```
memcpy(&b,&array[2],sizeof(array));
```

This copies the pointer `array[2]` onto `b` (equivalent to `b=array[2]`), so that `delete[] b` and `delete[] array[2]` later try to delete the same array. Perhaps you meant to copy the array:

```
memcpy(b,array[2],10*sizeof(*b));
```

The underlying problem is that you're messing around with manual allocation, raw pointers, and untyped C-library functions. Using `std::vector`, with automatic memory management and assignment, is far simpler and less error-prone.

Comment: +1 for explanation of how/why the bug leads to memory corruption.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! If that was the problem, why wasn't there such an error for just double?

Comment: @PopulationXplosive: It's just as wrong if you use `double` rather than `complex`, and I get exactly the same diagnostic from Valgrind. Of course, undefined behaviour doesn't necessarily lead to a helpful error, which is why it's a much better idea to avoid all these error-prone shenanigans.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `memcpy` is wrong - it should be:

```
memcpy(b, array[2], 10 * sizeof(*b));
```

Note that you are writing C++ code as if it were C - you should not be using `memcpy` and other C libraries, and you should try to use proper C++ idioms such as `std::vector` rather than raw C-style arrays, otherwise you won't enjoy the benefits of C++ and will run into all the usual C pitfalls such as the memory corruption bug you just encountered.